# initLoader call not taking "this" as third argument. Full error below

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

The error

> initLoader(int, android.os.Bundle, android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks)' in 'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager' cannot be applied to '(int, null, group15.cop4331project.MyReportsFragment)

I've read all of the answers about the support libraries, but it's not that. I'm trying to populate this fragment with a list from a SQLite Database. I would really like to figure out why this isn't working. Also, I think I'm using OnCreateView and OnActivityCreated correctly, but I'm not sure.

**My imports**

```
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
```

**My Code**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks < Cursor > {

    //adapter for the ListView
    MyCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    View rootView;

    public MyReportsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_list, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Find the listview which will be populated with the data
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Setup an Adapter to create a list item for each row of  data in the Cursor.
        mCursorAdapter = new ReportCursorAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        listView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        // Setup the item click listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ?>adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditReportActivity.class);

                Uri currentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ReportEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);

                // Set the URI on the data field of the intent
                intent.setData(currentUri);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Kick off the loader
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(REPORT_LOADER, null, this);
        //getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(REPORT_LOADER, null, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initLoader should be called in onActivityCreated so that part is ok.

i encountered a asimilar problem, the solotion was related to the support v4 lib. change this import statement:
`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`
to: 
`import android.app.Fragment;`
and use: `import android.app.LoaderManager;`
(make sure you are not using support v4 anywhere in your project)

this is based on the code you posted, if you could post all the imort statement  that could be helpful

hope this helps

Comment: I guess that copy and pasting several import statements (which I did from the other answers) didn't work for some reason, but this seems to do the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: So, unfortunately, if I remove the support v4 library then I cannot implement swiping between tabs. I don't suppose you know a way that I can do both swiping and what I am attempting above?

Comment: Actually i had that problem too :), if you are using a viewPager with a fragmentPagerAdapter, you can import the support.v13 library using: compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.1.1' in your gradle file. the v13 support library contains a FragmentPagerAdapter Class that can handle android.app.Fragments. good luck J